# compare c input with $$ and `tty` &

Tags: c, string, input, char, compare

I want to compare the user input with `$$` to see if it matches one of the arguments of user input. I also want to compare to see if `` `tty' & `` matches one of the arguments of user input.
something like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argv[4] == '`tty` &') { //line 31
    fprintf(stderr, "error %s\n", argv[4]);
    return(1);
     }

    if (argv[2] == '&&') { //line 36
    fprintf(stderr, "error%s\n", argv[2]);
    return(1);
    }
}
```

I get the error message

```
ai.c:31:21: warning: character constant too long for its type
ai.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
ai.c:31: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
ai.c:36:21: warning: multi-character character constant
ai.c:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you compare strings in c you should use `strcmp` as well as what Femaref said on trying to go to the integer `argc`

```
if (strcmp (argv[4], "`tty` &") != 0)
```

also, in order not to get some exception you should check the quantity if parameters in args:

```
if(argc >=5)
```

Comment: glad to be of service @Gantavya :)

Answer (score 0):

1. argc is int . So you can't subscript this.
2. For strings you need double quotes.
3. You should try to use strcmp/strncmp function for comparing strings.

Read a good C book . Download here [K & R](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2008/resource/The_C_Programming_Language.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

First ' ' is only for  characters, and you use it as for a string entry. It couldn't work.
Then you cannot compare strings entries with ' == ' use strcmp.
To finish the error error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer is due to the use of argc instead of argv ...

you code should be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

if (strcmp(argv[4], "`tty` ") == 0) { //line 31
     fprintf(stderr, "error %s\n", argv[4]);
     return(1);
}
if (strcmp(argv[2],"&&") == 0)  { //line 36
    fprintf(stderr, "error%s\n", argv[2]);
    return(1);
}
}
```